# pandas-like resampling with week frequency in DolphinDB

Tags: pandas, group-by, resampling, dolphindb

pandas supports resampling with many kinds of frequencies. To implement a pandas-like resampling in DolphinDB, I could use a group-by clause with the group-by column being a function call on a temporal column. For example, to resample with month frequency, I can write a SQL like this:

```
select count(*) from t group by month(myDate)
```

Things are a little different when it comes to the week frequency because DolphinDB has no functions like `week`. In addition, I'd like to resample by a specific day in a week, say, Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

"W" indicates week frequency:

```
orca_dataframe.resample("W", on="myDate").count()
```

To resample every Tuesday of week:

```
orca_dataframe.resample("W-TUE", on="myDate").count()
```